# What is the role of "&" and "*" on operator overloading?

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

```
Pareja& operator+ (const Pareja &parametro1, const Pareja &parametro2) {
    return *(new Pareja(parametro1.a + parametro2.a, parametro1.b + parametro2.b));
}
```

I don't understand why we use "&" like in `Pareja&` and "*" like in `return *(...`

And when we have to use it and when we not.

When I read about Overloading Operators this "topic" is given as known.

Comment: You'll find an answer in any C++ course. Plus this code snippet is crappy and leaks memory on purpose.

Comment: @YSC Thanks a lot for your constructive comment.

Comment: @YSC: This doesn't necessarily leak memory--though it does require a fair amount of care to avoid its leaking memory.

Comment: @JerryCoffin An excessive amount of care, asking to delete what is aliased by the return value. Even `a + b + c` leaks.

Comment: @YSC: Yes--don't get me wrong. I'm not saying it's a good design. I'm just saying it *is* (barely) possible to use it in a way that doesn't leak memory.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I did get that; it's just too hard not to criticize this implementation ;) I'm making a huge effort right now not to add another layer on top of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to operate on objects, not their copies, so this is why here are ampersands '&'. Const keyword indicates that You will not modify their values. The asterisk '*' is dereferencing a pointer to the newly created object, which is in this case leads to a memory leak as YSC said before. 
It is not allowed to create a new object and then do not store it in any container/pointer. 
You are responsible for their lifetime.